# Can reading STDIN conflict many writings from different processes?

Tags: stdin, write

One of my applications (Let's say "A") pushes its some alerts into STDIN and that app's shell script reads that STDIN and processes it. In the same way, there can be another applications (called B, C, D) which may pushes its outputs to the STDIN.

I want to know that can my first application may read the other applications' STDIN pushes and a conflict can occur in data ? (when I read STDIN of A, can there be contents of B , C STDIN ?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no useful "STDIN of A" in this scenario. The STDIN is always that of **your** application. a, b and c write to their STDOUT, the parentheses put them together, and the pipe connects the result to yourapp's STDIN. Where, yes, all those STDOUTs might conflict (one after the other, not intertwined).

```
( a ; b; c ) | yourapp
```

or

```
( a && b && c ) | yourapp
```

It is unclear whether you have a, b, and c inside a shell script ("that app's shell script") and whether it is the same script for all. If it is not, then the scripts are your "apps" and you are in the scenario above. If it is, you must have something like

```
while ...; do
    read something
    a
    b
    c
done
```

In the above scenario, the "read" will read the common STDIN of the outer application, again in order, possibly blocking if there is nothing to read, but I don't see how A can push anything in there.

I can't be sure, but I suspect this might a case where named pipes or message brokers might come in handy.